# How do I test if a JS variable does equal either of two values?

Tags: javascript, variables, testing

Is there a short way to test if a variable is equal to two string, in plain JS5?

My code is like:

```
var type = 'display'
if (type === 'display' || type === 'filter') { ... }
```

Is there a way to make shorter, like:

```
if ( type === ('display' || 'filter') ) { ... }
```

Comment: You mean, is there a way to test if a variable is equal to *one of two strings*, yes there is, you're already doing it, the first example is correct.

Comment: Even if you could do it like your second example, how much are you really saving? Plus you're sacrificing readability.

Comment: there's no need to shorten it, but you can do `if (['display','filter'].includes(type) )`

Comment: Alternatively via compiled regex: `/^(display|filter)$/.test(type)` - might be more performant if you compare to a lot of strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought your original post was pretty straight forward and thought it was a perfectly fine answer to your problem.

Having said that you can use RegEx like @le_m mentioned.  I just tested this in the console and this works.

The '//' tell the interpreter that we will be starting a regular expression.  The parenthesis allow us to declare a subexpression.  A subexpression that will be evaluated independently of other expressions.

The 'i' stands for insensitive.  In this case it isn't entirely necessary but I think it might be useful for you down the road. The 'i' will allow you to avoid casing issues.  Also, should you pass in longer strings that contain 'display', or 'type' in a sentence, this regex will also find those.

```
var type = 'display';
if (/(type|display)/i.test(type)) { 
  console.log('word found')
}
```

Comment: You need to include ^ and $, otherwise words like 'linotype' and 'displayed' will match, too.